# how to handle ActionResult in custome class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have a class (in project by mvc4 razor on .net 4.5) and want to handle a Redirecting method on it and do not want inherit from controller class.
 how can i handle this?it returns ActionResult to redirecting user in some cases like log outing

my main class:

```
public class SecuritySrv 
{
  public ActionResult Redirect()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Account", new { area = "" });
    }
}
```

and i want to use it in some controllers  like below:

```
 public ActionResult AccountHome()
    {
      SecuritySrv SecurityService =new SecuritySrv()
       if(.....)
      return SecurityService.Redirect();


     return view();
   }
```

Comment: yes in visual studio can not detect RedirectToAction it available in Controller class

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code anywhere, and you don't need an UrlHelper or access to the context, so you don't need to inherit the Controller class.

```
        RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"controller", "Profile"}, 
                {"action", "Users"}, 
                {"area", ""}
            };
        return new RedirectToRouteResult(rvd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectToAction` method of controller is just a helper for creating `RedirectToRouteResult`, you can create it by yourself in your class:

```
public class SecuritySrv 
{
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        routeValues["action"] = "Logout";
        routeValues["controller"] = "Account";
        routeValues["area"] = "";

        return new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
    }
}
```

And call this method from your controller in the way you wanted to.